# hibernate search without database

Tags: java, lucene, hibernate-search

Is it possible to use hibernate-search only for it's annotations (bean => document/document => bean mapping), without using a database at all? If so, are there any online samples that show basically how to set this up?

I found the following: http://mojodna.net/2006/10/02/searchable-annotation-driven-indexing-and-searching-with-lucene.html, but I'd prefer hibernate-search if it supports my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's possible because when you enable Hibernate search you are enabling that on a Entity and that Entity has references to the table and the search index.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. Please see my answer below, which is correct but a bit updated: it's all quiet easy to do nowaways.

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate search 3.4 has decoupled the query engine from Hibernate Core. For instance, Hibernate Search is reused to implement queries with Infinispan. I don't know if the code is packaged so that you could use HS with, let's say Spring and JDBCTemplate (something I would like to do). That's a lead I will investigate later but maybe you can check it out...

Answer (score 2):

Starman is correct, Hibernate Search in version 3.4 is abstracting the search engine from Hibernate Core, and the Infinispan Query is an integration example which works fine without a database. There would be no problems with Spring either, but you'd need to make sure to send update event to the query engine so that the index doesn't get out of synch. When using Hibernate the advantage is that it transparently listens for changes to the database and applies them to the index at transaction commit, so the index is always in synch (or close, if configuring Search to use async backends).

I'd suggest to look into the code of Infinispan Query, as it's very small and just delegating calls to expose an *Infinispan flavoured API*. Most of the code is tests or integration to properly manage the lifecycle of the engine: start and stop it together with Infinispan.